# I showed him some snapshots that ... "I had taken in London” or "I took in London"

Tags: past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I understand the past perfect tense and I clearly understand the meaning of the sentence below.

- I showed him some snapshots that I had taken in London.

However, a friend of mine asked me if the sentence below is OK.

- I showed him some snapshots that I took in London.

In my opinion, this sentence has no problem and can convey the same meaning as above.  In this case, you don't need to use the past perfect tense even if the speaker had taken the snapshots way before s/he showed them to his/her friend because it is perfectly clear which event happened first.  There would be no confusion if you used "took" instead of "had taken" in this sentence.

Having said that, since I'm not a native speaker of English, I cannot be sure if I am right.  Please help me answer my friend's question.

Comment: As ever, you don't *need* to use the Perfect in the cited context, so my advice is to stick with Simple Past. Just because you can *justify* the Perfect doesn't mean you *should* use it. Think [KISS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)